# I need to go through each and every row of a datatable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I have a data table named `dt` which is a SQL table converted.

All the data was sent from the server so I had to encrypt it. Now I need to decrypt every cell.

I wanted to do it like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        row[i] = r.Decrypt(row[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Decrypt works fine but `row[i] = r.Decrypt(row[i].ToString());` give me the number of the column instead of its content, how do I get the content?

to make the post make more sense.

i want `row[i] = r.Decrypt(a string representing the value of row[i]);`

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    col.ToString();
                }
            }

Comment: Why are you using hand-rolled encryption in the first place? Almost all databases use HTTPS connection encryption. SQL Server allows encrypting data at the table *and application driver* level.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to interact with a datatable

```
  foreach(DataRow row in dt .Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn column in dt .Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
```

In your case you are literally passing an int to your row, because You are using count property.

** Edit
This is in case Your datarow contains an object.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 2");
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            dataRow.ItemArray = new object[]{"line 1 column 1", "line 1 column 2"
            };
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    var text = row[column.ToString()];

                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
```

Result
[image]

If none of this work, We would have to see how Your data row is created.

Comment: it gives me an exeption.
cannot convert object to string and tostring returns the number for the row ie 123

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the other logic (Decrypt) is working fine and you just need to fetch the column content/values then you can try something like:

```
   foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
      foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
      {
          // you can insert your logic to use column value row[column] here
          Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count ; j++)
            {
                string cellValue = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                dt.Rows[i][j] = r.Decrypt(cellValue);


            }
        }
```

Comment: If someone else's answer helped you well, you don't need to repost the same answer. You could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.